# Can't paste Password into Ubuntu Software Center Log-in Field

Tags: software-center, gwibber, keepass

When i click on the buy button in the software center it instructs me to login, however as i'm using Keepass for saving my passwords i would like to paste it in but it wont let me...

the same applies to gwibber when i try to input my facebook password.

it is possible to input manually but since i picked a long password this would take very long.

Unfortunately until now i couldn't find a solution other than just not logging in or stop using the password manager.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using keepassx instead of keepass.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried pasting through the popup menu, well I'd say that is reasonable for a password field to have the Paste entry disabled. In some cases the keyboard shortcuts might work, so try Ctrl+V and Shift+Ins.

Answer (score 0):

I also experience the scenario in Gwibber where I copy the username/password from Keepass but cannot paste into login fields using the mouse paste menu or ctrl + v. The workaround to this is to

- copy the login detail (user name or password) from within Keepass per usual
- switch to a text editor such as gedit
- check if the mouse paste menu or ctrl + v works there (on my system they do)
- highlight the pasted text in the text editor and copy (I use ctrl + c)
- switch to Gwibber's login screens and now paste the text using ctrl + v
- the copied text will now appear

I have applied this approach to several applications where my details would not paste directly out of Keepass. (including - if I recall correctly - the Ubuntu Software Center)